# Python - Access generic object in line if line meets conditional from a file read operation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with an input data file `data.dat`, and I've written a class called `GetData` to access values in the file in a way that works well for my problem.

The way I've organized my problem is creating one module for all of my functions `myfn.py` and a main module `code.py` which does the important operations and uses various functions from `myfn.py` in the process.

This is my issue: both modules require some data form `data.dat` to work.

My current attempt at handling this is as follows; explicitly defining values in both modules so they can both access the necessary data:

```
# myfn.py

# Operations to pull values out of data.dat to access in module
filename = 'data.dat'
datafile = GetData(filename)
datafile.readValues()

# val1, val2 and val3 are arbitrary constants from from data.dat
val1 = datafile.val1
val2 = datafile.val2
val3 = datafile.val3
```

Now if I go to my main module, it's more or less identical but doesn't use the class again.

```
# code.py

import myfn

val1 = myfn.val1
val2 = myfn.val2
val3 = myfn.val3
```

To me, this seems inefficient and redundant. What I was hoping to do was something like this:

```
# myfn.py

# Use file operation to "inspect" module for specific lines
selfchk = __file__[(__file__.rfind('\\') + 1):]
f = open(selfchk)
info = f.readlines()
f.close() 

# Pseudo code
toimport = []
for line in info:
    if 'datafile' in line and 'GetData' not in line and 'readValues' not in line:
        toimport.append(value in info.index(line)) # Where value is object defined at line

# ... all other myfn.py code already shown above
```

This way, I would only need to import one list into `code.py` instead of a bunch of floats. So, the "ideal" version of `code.py` would look more like:

```
# code.py

import myfn

(val1, val2, val3) = myfn.toimport
```

So, does anyone know how I could go about extracting an object from line if I only know its line number? Or better yet, a different way to go about this issue if you have a suggestion?